# Scanning via intent code missing

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code

I am currently developing an app that will have the function to scan apps by the intent function to open the scanner, This is my existing code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bt, bt2;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
                    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getResults);



                    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             // do initiatescan
                        }
                    });

                    bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanResults.class);
                            startActivity(intent);



                        }

                    });



                }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
                    {
                        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                        if (requestCode == 0) {
                            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                            }
                        }
                    }


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

I know that i need to add

`IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                    integrator.initiateScan();`

But i dont know where.
Could anyone please help me with this simple question, Thanks in advance.

Comment: To start, where do you think it goes? what have you tried? You seem to have code with a big obvious labeled place where this code goes, so, what happens when you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         // do initiatescan
                    }
                });
```

so **do initiatescan** will do the scanning so i guess your code should be here only...

Comment: I assumed that that would cause conflict with the first button

Comment: what is the first button meant for ??